# Is it possible to have a unique .bash_history file per host?

Tags: bash, nfs

My home directory is mounted on an NFS mount.  The commands I use on one machine are usually quite different to those on another.  Is it possible to have easy host write to it's own history file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It certainly is. You just have to change the name of your history file on each host. In your `.bash_profile` put something like:

```
export HISTFILE="${HOME}/.bash_history.`hostname`"
```

Comment: My bash wouldn't expand ~, so I had to use ${HOME}

    export HISTFILE="${HOME}/.bash_history.$(hostname)"

Comment: I only wanted the first part of the hostname (i.e. before the first dot) so I used `export HISTFILE="${HOME}/.bash_history.${HOSTNAME%%.*}"`

Answer (score 1):

There is the environment variable `HISTFILE`, which controls where the history file is. You could try to create a login script that resets `HISTFILE` according to your hostname/IP.